# Zoom to selected feature extent using Carto and Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, carto, carto-js

I am trying to use the getBounds and setBounds functions to zoom to the extent of a selected polyline feature in Carto. The feature has been selected using an SQL query. I want to zoom to the extent of the selected feature but it is not working! See code below:

```
// Add dropdown selection function
const selector = $(".js-dropdown-selector");
// Change SQL query with dropdown selection
selector.on('change',function(e){
  let value = $(".js-dropdown-selector option:selected").val();
  console.log("You have selected Route " + value + ".");
  if(value == 'all'){
    source.setQuery('SELECT * FROM aggregate');
  } else {
    source.setQuery("SELECT * FROM aggregate WHERE routenumbe = '" + value + "'")
  };
});
map.getBounds(source);
map.setBounds(getBounds);
```

Comment: Race condition. `getBounds()` and `setBounds()` are running only once, and not on every change of the selector.

Comment: ah okay - how do I rectify that?

Answer (score 1):

Several base problems here. The code that runs on every change of the drop-down selector...

```
selector.on('change',function(e){
  let value = $(".js-dropdown-selector option:selected").val();
  console.log("You have selected Route " + value + ".");
  if(value == 'all'){
    source.setQuery('SELECT * FROM aggregate');
  } else {
    source.setQuery("SELECT * FROM aggregate WHERE routenumbe = '" + value + "'")
  };
});
```

... is not running any `getBounds()` or `setBounds()` calls at all.

Now, the `getBounds()` call...

```
map.getBounds(source);
```

... does not take any arguments, [as per the Leaflet documentation](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#map-getbounds).

A naïve approach would be to perform those calls right after the `setQuery()` call...

```
selector.on('change',function(e){
  let value = $(".js-dropdown-selector option:selected").val();
  console.log("You have selected Route " + value + ".");
  if(value == 'all'){
    source.setQuery('SELECT * FROM aggregate');
  } else {
    source.setQuery("SELECT * FROM aggregate WHERE routenumbe = '" + value + "'")
  };

  // TODO: Somehow get the bounds of the (updated?) source here

});
```

... but, [quoting the Carto.js docs](https://carto.com/developers/carto-js/reference/#cartosourcesqlsetquery), `source.setQuery` takes some time to update the data source:

> Update the query. This method is asynchronous and returns a promise which is resolved when the style is changed successfully. It also fires a 'queryChanged' event.

... so it's important here to know [how to handle `Promise`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises). The asynchronicity is obvious when fiddling with [Carto's `setQuery()` example](https://carto.com/developers/carto-js/examples/#example-change-the-source) - it takes time since the user clicks on a checkbox until the data is updated.

So if you *don't want* to zoom into the *previously* loaded geometries, things should look something like:

```
selector.on('change',function(e){
  let value = $(".js-dropdown-selector option:selected").val();
  var query = "";
  console.log("You have selected Route " + value + ".");
  if(value == 'all'){
    query = ('SELECT * FROM aggregate');
  } else {
    query = ("SELECT * FROM aggregate WHERE routenumbe = '" + value + "'")
  };

  source.setQuery(query).then(function() {
      // TODO: Somehow get the bounds of the updated source here
  });
});
```

With that out of the way, now it's time to worry about getting the bounds. The problem is that a [Carto source](https://carto.com/developers/carto-js/reference/#cartosourcebase) doesn't have any methods to get the bounds of the data. Nor it can be done by referring to the [Carto layer](https://carto.com/developers/carto-js/reference/#cartolayerlayer), because the Leaflet implementation of Carto layers are  raster-based, and the documentation doesn't show any way of fetching any data bounds either.

Instead, you might want to experiment with other approaches such as requesting GeoJSON data and instantiating `L.GeoJSON` instances from there, as shown in [Carto's drop-down example](https://carto.com/developers/carto-js/examples/#example-dropdown-menu-with-data-from-carto-dataset)

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer! I will take a look at the JSON approach.